# ObjectContext disposal in EF + Repository ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository

so, I'm getting a `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.` error when I try to access the `ObjectContext` through a repository in an `OnActionExecuting` `ActionFilterAttribute`.

My `ActionFilterAttribute` checks for the existence of an HTTP cookie. If it exists it verifies it with the database, refreshes it's expiration, and then adds it to the `Controller` `ViewData` collection so it can be accessed by `ActionResult`'s. If it doesn't exist, then it redirects the user to the login page.

The filter half works because when an HTTP cookie *does* exist and it attempts to grab the concrete object out of the database, it crashes with the above error message.

Because of the number of layers that are in place, I'm gonna go ahead and post the code to all of them, `VerifyCookieAttribute.cs`, `CookieRepository.cs` and `Repository_1.cs`. Lastly, although it probably does not make any difference, the error occurs in the `SelectSingle` method of `Repository_1.cs`.

Dependency Injection is by Ninject 2.2.1.0. Lazy loading is currently *enabled*, but either setting produces the same error.

Anyway, I'd appreciate some guidance in where I'm going wrong with all of this. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
//  VerifyCookieAttribute.cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
internal class VerifyCookieAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    [Inject]
    public CookieRepository Repository { private get; set; }

    private HttpRequestBase Request = null;
    private HttpResponseBase Response = null;

    private readonly bool Administration = false;
    private readonly bool Customers = false;

    private readonly string[] ExcludedPaths = new string[2] {
        "/Administration",
        "/Customers"
    };

    public VerifyCookieAttribute(
        bool Administration,
                    bool Customers) {
    this.Administration = Administration;
    this.Customers = Customers;
}

    public override void OnActionExecuting(
        ActionExecutingContext ActionExecutingContext) {
        this.Request = ActionExecutingContext.HttpContext.Request;

        if (!this.ExcludedPaths.Contains(this.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)) {
            this.Response = ActionExecutingContext.HttpContext.Response;

            if (this.Exists()) {
                Cookie Cookie = this.Get();

                this.Refresh(Cookie);

                ActionExecutingContext.Controller.ViewData.Add("Cookie", Cookie);

                if (this.Administration) {
                    ActionExecutingContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new {
                        area = "Administration",
                        controller = "Administration",
                        action = "Dashboard"
                    }));
                } else if (this.Customers) {
                    //  Do Nothing
                };
            } else if (!this.Exists() && !this.Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected) {
                if (this.Administration) {
                    ActionExecutingContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new {
                        area = "Administration",
                        controller = "Administration",
                        action = "Default"
                    }));
                } else if (this.Customers) {
                    ActionExecutingContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new {
                        area = "Customers",
                        controller = "Customers",
                        action = "Default"
                    }));
                };
            };
        };
    }

    private bool Exists() {
        string Token = this.GetHttpCookieToken();

        return (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Token) && (Token.Length == 256));
    }

    private Cookie Get() {
        string Token = this.GetHttpCookieToken();

        Cookie Cookie = this.Repository.SelectSingle(
            c =>
                (c.Token == Token));

        return (Cookie);
    }

    private string GetHttpCookieToken() {
        if (this.Request.Cookies["NWP"] != null) {
            return this.Request.Cookies["NWP"]["Token"];
        };

        return (string.Empty);
    }

    private void Refresh(
        Cookie Cookie) {
        if (Cookie.RefreshStamp <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)) {
            this.Repository.RefreshCookie(Cookie.CookieId);

            this.SetHttpCookie(Cookie);
        };
    }

    private void SetHttpCookie(
        Cookie Cookie) {
        this.Response.Cookies["NWP"]["Token"] = Cookie.Token;
        this.Response.Cookies["NWP"].Expires = Cookie.RefreshStamp.AddHours(1);
    }
}

//   CookieRepository.cs
public sealed class CookieRepository : Repository<Cookie> {
    [Inject]
    public CookieRepository(
        Entities Entities)
        : base(Entities, true) {
    }

    public void RefreshCookie(
        int CookieId) {
        this.Entities.ExecuteFunction("RefreshCookie", new ObjectParameter("CookieId", CookieId));
    }
}

//  Repository`1.cs
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class {
    protected readonly Entities Entities = null;

    private readonly IObjectSet<TEntity> EntitySet = null;

    [Inject]
    public Repository(
        Entities Entities)
        : this(Entities, true) {
    }

    [Inject]
    public Repository(
        Entities Entities,
        bool CreateEntitySet) {
        this.Entities = Entities;

        if (CreateEntitySet) {
            this.EntitySet = this.Entities.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
        };
    }

    public virtual void Delete(
        TEntity TEntity) {
        this.EntitySet.DeleteObject(TEntity);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(
        TEntity TEntity) {
        this.EntitySet.AddObject(TEntity);
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Select() {
        return this.EntitySet;
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Select(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Selector) {
        return this.EntitySet.Where(Selector);
    }

    public virtual bool SelectAny(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Selector) {
        return this.EntitySet.Any(Selector);
    }

    public virtual IList<TEntity> SelectList() {
        return this.EntitySet.ToList();
    }

    public virtual IList<TEntity> SelectList(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Selector) {
        return this.EntitySet.Where(Selector).ToList();
    }

    private IList<TEntity> SelectOrderedList(
        bool Ascending,
        params Expression<Func<TEntity, IComparable>>[] Orderers) {
        IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> Queryable = null;

        foreach (Expression<Func<TEntity, IComparable>> Orderer in Orderers) {
            if (Queryable == null) {
                Queryable = (Ascending ? this.EntitySet.OrderBy(Orderer) : this.EntitySet.OrderByDescending(Orderer));
            } else {
                Queryable = (Ascending ? Queryable.ThenBy(Orderer) : Queryable.ThenByDescending(Orderer));
            };
        };

        return (Queryable.ToList());
    }

    public virtual IList<TEntity> SelectOrderedList(
        params Expression<Func<TEntity, IComparable>>[] Orderers) {
        return this.SelectOrderedList(true, Orderers);
    }

    public virtual IList<TEntity> SelectOrderedDescendingList(
        params Expression<Func<TEntity, IComparable>>[] Orderers) {
        return this.SelectOrderedList(false, Orderers);
    }

    public virtual TEntity SelectSingle(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Selector) {
        return this.EntitySet.Single(Selector);
    }

    public virtual void Update() {
        this.Entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Where(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Selector) {
        return this.EntitySet.Where(Selector);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the stack trace per @jfar's request:

`` System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +8550458
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery1.GetResults(Nullable1 forMergeOption) +46
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +44
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable1 source) +184
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b_3(IEnumerable1 sequence) +41
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable1 query, Expression queryRoot) +59
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +150
   System.Linq.Queryable.Single(IQueryable1 source, Expression1 predicate) +300
   {WITHHELD}.Repositories.Repository1.SelectSingle(Expression1 Selector) in C:\Projects{WITHHELD}{WITHHELD}\Repositories\Repository1.cs:98
   VerifyCookieAttribute.Get() in C:\Projects\{WITHHELD}\{WITHHELD}\Attributes\VerifyCookieAttribute.cs:100
   VerifyCookieAttribute.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ActionExecutingContext) in C:\Projects\{WITHHELD}\{WITHHELD}\Attributes\VerifyCookieAttribute.cs:55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func1 continuation) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_DisplayClass17.b_14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_DisplayClass17.b_14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass81.b_7(IAsyncResult ) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_DisplayClasse.b_d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b_0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8862381
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184 ``

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of where the exception is thrown?  Sounds like a lazy loading issue but would need the stack to see.

Comment: @jfar, I updated the post with the stack trace. I don't know how to properly format it for SO, so I did what I could...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using mvc 3.

> In previous versions of ASP.NET MVC,
>   action filters are create per request
>   except in a few cases. This behavior
>   was never a guaranteed behavior but
>   merely an implementation detail and
>   the contract for filters was to
>   consider them stateless. In ASP.NET
>   MVC 3, filters are cached more
>   aggressively. Therefore, any custom
>   action filters which improperly store
>   instance state might be broken.

This means that attributes are **not** created for every request, therefor any `InRequestScope` injection won't work. You will need to either inject `IServiceProvider` and get your repository with that on each request or create new context manually.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas! I actually remember reading that a while back, but I never bothered to assimilate it since I wasn't using DI at the time...